# If clicked img src contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all how can i check If clicked img src contains specific text if then do some functions?

Example:

`<img src="file:///C:/path/img4-dog.jpg">,
<img src="file:///C:/path/img4-cat.jpg">`

run alert if clicked img src contains 'dog' something like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('img').click(function(){
   if (this.src.indexOf("dog") != -1) 
      alert('contains dog');
})
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('img').click(function(e) {

    if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf('dog') != -1) {
        alert('this contains dog');
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('img').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr('src').toLowerCase().indexOf("dog") >= 0){
       alert('text found');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('src').indexOf('img4-dog') >= 0) alert('found');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
   // Use a regular expression to find a match
    var test = imgsrc.search(/dog/);
    if (test > -1) {
      // do something
    }
});
```